# Facebook application development - which option, and may I use jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I have read the documentations at Facebook. I have browsed through books on Facebook development and I am reeling from the options, restrictions. There is MockAjax, FBML, FBJavascript and the PHP API. And then there is an option of launching the application from inner frame.

I guess there are 2 questions. When do you use the FB options, and is it possible to run my own PHP page using jQuery with the inner frame option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the PEAR module Services::Facebook, and of course jQuery.

Most of the FB options are hooks for FBConnect, etc.  They are handy, but with any agile software project, get the base functions done, then scale.

Comment: I understand that PEAR is a large library; can I just use PEAR Facebook w/o the rest?

Comment: PEAR itself is a PHP code repository.

You can download the code without using the PEAR interface to install it.
http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Facebook